# RegEx match before string or all / Remove string from match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I tried to search but could not find my case. I need to match all before string "part 1" or "part 2" etc. But in case there is not any "part x" string to match all. Example:

- Any words here part 1
- Any words here part 2
- Any words here

It should always return "Any words here". I have tried this

`(.+)(?=\spart\s\d|\sPart\s\d)`

but it does not match when "part x" is missing. Other solution would be to just remove any "part x" string from match.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Try `((?! part [0-9]).)+( part [0-9]+)?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^.+?(?=part\s*1|part\s*2|$)
```

Use `anchors` ored to `part 1` and `part 2`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/5

or

```
^.+?(?=part\s*\d+|$)
```

Comment: I need the match without "part x" string in return.

Comment: Thank you - this one works in the app

`^(.+?)(?=part ([0-9]*)|$)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(.*?)(?: part \d+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zR2wI5/1)

Comment: Hi, not working here http://regexr.com/3ckld and unfortunately also not in the app. I am trying to amend scraper addon in KODI - see http://kodi.wiki/view/RegEx_tutorial

Comment: I can not flag the expression, see: <expression noclean="1">^(.*?)(?: part \d+)?$</expression>

Comment: I don't know `kodi` but as you can see from above demo sites this regex pretty well.